# Pack a git repository locally that respects .gitignore

Tags: git

I have a git repo locally which has a bunch of files in .gitignore (e.g. node_modules). I want to send this repo to a friend in an email as a zip attachment. Is there a way to create a git package which would respect .gitignore? I know I can duplicate a folder and manually delete all unneeded files but is there an easier way? Like npm has `npm pack` that creates a tarball locally which looks exactly like it would if it was to be published (i.e. respecting .npmignore). Is there equivalent for git? Thanks.

EDIT:

To clarify, I want the result to be the same as if I pushed to a remote repo and someone pulled it. `git archive` creates a snapshot of the repo removing `.git` file. It seems like the thing I want is `git clone src_repo dest_repo`, that will clone my local repository taking into account `.gitignore`

Comment: Why not make a push and your friend make the clone on your pc?

Comment: It's more of a hypothetical question :) Say I don't want to get a github acc or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Git bundle file with `git bundle create` that contains the branch or branches that you want to include. If you want to include all branches, you can use `git bundle create --all`.

Your friend can then clone from it by running `git clone BUNDLE-FILE DIRECTORY`, which will create a new repository in the directory. Similarly, it can be used as a remote from which to pull simply by specifying the file name instead of a normal remote name or URL.

This is the preferred way for transferring Git repositories via a file. You generally don't want to transfer the full repository including the `.git` directory because Git assumes that things such as hooks and configuration are not subject to modification from other users, so zipping a clone isn't a secure way to transfer a repository.

You should not need to zip the resulting file, since Git will already have compressed the data. If you do, it will be much faster if you disable compression.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for, is git archive.

See [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) for the exact documentation.

Comment: hmm after doing some more research it seems like `git clone` is actually the one I want. `git archive` creates a sort of snapshot of the repo and doesn't contain `.git` folder. I want the result to be the same as if the repo was pushed and then pulled by another person.